# Netsuite Script: what causes THAT_RECORD_IS_NOT_EDITABLE error?

Tags: javascript, oracle, netsuite

I am trying to modify a shipping order record using a netsuite script v2.

```
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */


define(['N/search', 'N/record'],

    function(search, record) {
        function afterSubmit(context) {
            if (context.type !== context.UserEventType.CREATE){
                 return;
            }

            try {
              // Get the current Record
              var salesOrder = context.newRecord;
              salesOrder.setValue({fieldId: 'custbody_route_vendor', value: 1});
              salesOrder.save({enableSourcing: true, ignoreMandatoryFields: true});

            } catch (error) {
              log.error({title: 'Error: ', details: error });
            }

        }

    return {
        afterSubmit: afterSubmit
    };
});
```

This seems to be pretty straight forward.  But when I save a sales order, it throws this error:

*{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"THAT_RECORD_IS_NOT_EDITABLE","message":"That record is not editable.","stack":["createError(N/error)...*

Which isn't very helpful because I don't know the types of things that would make a record uneditable.

I searched the docs and the internet, but can't find an reference for this error.  The docs for that save function does not address possible errors:

https://system.na2.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4267286323.html

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `context` passed to the `afterSubmit` function is read only.  You cannot modify and then save the newly created record.  You would need to either:

1. Use the `beforeSubmit` function instead.  Using `beforeSubmit` allows you to change the record as you're doing, before it's submitted to the database - however, you should not call `Record.save()` on it, as the system will save the modified record after your `beforeSubmit` completes.
2. You can also use the `afterSubmit` function, but for this you need to load the record separately, modify it as required and then save.

Comment: Option 1 is usually the way to go. There are going to be performance costs in reading and writing the record a second time.

Comment: Correct.  I just mentioned option 2 for completeness, and also as this is necessary when creating or modifying _other_ records based on data from the saved transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest using `record.submitFields` in `afterSubmit` instead of loading record and then saving it. It will save you execution units.

```
record.submitFields({
    id: context.newRecord.id,
    type: context.newRecord.type,
    values: {'custbody_route_vendor' : '1'}
})
```

Comment: This is a good answer but I am updated a select field, which I don't believe can but updated with submitFields.